CORS IN Spring Boot
In an spring boot application I get the CORS exception from the FE
I have anotation on top of the controller and also in the configuration of the spring but still having the same issue..
Is there anyone else facing the same issue?
I paste what i have already add to the project but without luck
 @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
                .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS") // Include PUT and OPTIONS
                .allowedMethods("*")
                .maxAge(3600L)
                .allowedHeaders("*")
                .exposedHeaders("Authorization")
                .allowCredentials(true);

}


@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200", methods = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.PUT, RequestMethod.DELETE, RequestMethod.OPTIONS})
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v1")
public class StudentsController {

Also in the interceptor I have added the following headers:
httpServletResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
httpServletResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,POST,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT");

This is the error:
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/v1/employees/' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Method PUT is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods in preflight response.

What's the point of doing the same thing in many places? Leave only addCorsMappings.

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
                .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS")
                .allowedHeaders("*")
                .exposedHeaders("Authorization")
                .allowCredentials(true)
                .maxAge(3600L);
    }
}

Make sure to remove any conflicting CORS annotations from your controller. The @CrossOrigin annotation is generally not necessary if you’re handling CORS globally.Since you are already using the CORS configuration, you should remove the manual header setting in your interceptor
httpServletResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
httpServletResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,POST,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT");

